# How To Set Constrains Using Programming In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I Have Created textviews And Want to set the constrains to up down right and left using code is there any way to do that ?

These are the four textviews. Can I constrain them to to top bottom left and right using code:

- textview1
- textview2
- textview3
- textview4

Comment: have you tried the ConstraintSet class? https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set constraints using `ConstraintSet` class.

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet().apply {
    clone(constraintLayout)
    connect(textView1.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP)
    connect(textView1.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, textView2.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
}
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```